# How do search engines handle URL's when it comes to SEO?

Tags: seo, url, url-rewriting

I am building a website using Symfony. At the moment, the "raw" URL's being used are like this:

```
www.localhost.com/mainpage/home
www.localhost.com/events/1/name-of-the-event
```

When the development of the website is finished, I will use the .htacess file to rewrite them as follows:

```
www.localhost.com (this is the mainpage/home URL)
www.localhost.com/events/name-of-the-event
```

My question is when the search engines crawl the site, will they be reading the old (non-rewrited) URL's or reading the rewrited URL's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They will see the rewrite URLs. In other words, whatever a user would see in their browser the search engines will see, too. This is because the rewrite is occurring behind the scenes so it is transparent to users and search engines alike.

Comment: Thank you. I did think that but i wanted to make sure :)